# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class

Tags: android, class, classnotfoundexception

i'm having this problem with my receiver...

```
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.rafael.acordenoponto.MonitoraGPS: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.rafael.acordenoponto.MonitoraGPS" on path: /data/app/com.rafael.acordenoponto-2.apk
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2285)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:137)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5031)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.rafael.acordenoponto.MonitoraGPS" on path: /data/app/com.rafael.acordenoponto-2.apk
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2280)
10-03 15:38:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(32219):    ... 10 more
```

had alread cleaned my project and rebuilt the path... I think that the problem is in this part "/data/app/com.rafael.acordenoponto-2.apk", but i don't know how to solve... i think the problem is there because my apk does not have that "-2" in the end... anyone know how to solve?

Here's the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MonitoraGPS">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="MONITORAR"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />     
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: That -2 in the end is added automatically don't worry because that's not the problem.

Comment: now i'm more worried than i was hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved!

the problem happened because .MonitoraGPS was in a different package...
so i just added the package name before .MonitoraGPS in the manifest and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It's no that.

1. Make sure your package-name is correct in anywhere (the java files, the xml files, AndroidManifest files...).
2. Right click on the project; goto **Build Path** --> **Configure Build Path** --> **Java Build Path** --> **Order and Export**. Then uncheck **Android Dependencies** and check *all third-party .jar*, if you have any.