# app-debuk.apk stopped working

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm new to Android programming and it's my first project with Gradle. In the past I used Maven for Java. So I made an application with Android studio and if I click on **Run** and select my phone it'll build and install the apk to my phone then opens itself and works fine.

So I would like to share my progress with one of my friend, so I clicked on **Make Project**, and it generated an ***app-debug.apk*** in **/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk** but if I try that to install my Application Force Close itself after launch with a text: "**Unfortunately the app stopped working**".

Here is my **build.gradle** *(Module:app)*:

[image: Overview]

and my **build.gradle** *(Project: Autosiskola)*:[image: Overview]

the error code:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.androidports.autosiskola/com.androidports.‌​autosiskola.MainActi‌​vity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.androidports.autosiskola.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.androidports.autosiskola-1/base.apk"],nativeL‌​ibraryDirectories=[/‌​data/app/com.android‌​ports.autosiskola-1/‌​lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]`

My Main Activity:

```
    package com.androidports.autosiskola;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText username, password;
Button login;
ProgressBar progressBar;

Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    conn = DBConnect.Connector();

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (username.toString().trim().isEmpty() && password.toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nincs felhasználónév / jelszó megadva!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.btnLogin:
                        new doMySQL().execute();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public class doMySQL extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    final String uname = username.getText().toString();
    final String passwd = password.getText().toString();
    String getUsername = null;
    String getPassword = null;
    String getPermission = null;
    String resValue = "undone";
    int exists = 0;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        conn = DBConnect.Connector();

        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT username FROM userList WHERE username=?");
            pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(uname));
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                getUsername = rs.getString(1);
            }
            pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT username FROM userList WHERE username=?");
            pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(uname));
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hibás felhasználónév / jelszó!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                resValue = "undone";
            }

            pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT password FROM userList WHERE username=?");
            pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(uname));
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                getPassword = rs.getString(1);
            }
            pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT password FROM userList WHERE username=?");
            pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(uname));
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hibás felhasználónév / jelszó!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                resValue = "undone";
            }

            pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT username FROM userList WHERE username=? AND password=?");
            pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(uname));
            pst.setString(2, String.valueOf(passwd));
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                exists = 1;
            }
            pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT username FROM userList WHERE username=? AND password=?");
            pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(uname));
            pst.setString(2, String.valueOf(passwd));
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hibás felhasználónév / jelszó!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                exists = 0;
                resValue = "undone";
            }

            if (exists == 1) {
                pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT permission FROM userList WHERE username=?");
                pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(uname));
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    getPermission = rs.getString(1);
                    resValue = "Done";
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hibás felhasználónév / jelszó!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return resValue;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if ("Done".equals(result)) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if ("teacher".equals(getPermission)) {
                Intent openTeacher = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TeacherLogin.class);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                startActivity(openTeacher);
            } else if ("student".equals(getPermission)) {
                Intent openStudent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StudentLogin.class);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                startActivity(openStudent);
            }
        } else if ("undone".equals(result)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hibás felhasználónév / jelszó!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The app works when I install it with the Run command on USB, but if I want to install app-debug.apk it didn't work.

I have a mysql-connector-java dependency inside my lib folder, that's all.

Comment: Hi, 1- if your app is crashing then add your error log here as formatted-code text.
2- don't post code as image but instead add it as formatted-code text.

Comment: If you have access to your friends device enable USB debugging and connect it to your machine and reopen your app and check the logcat to gain more information about what caused the crash

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.androidports.autosiskola/com.androidports.autosiskola.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.androidports.autosiskola.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.androidports.autosiskola-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.androidports.autosiskola-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185237/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class

Comment: You're missing the manifest... Gradle isn't the problem, also, why do you insist on screenshots instead of copy and pasting code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting fact: When I copy the app-debug.apk to my SDCard with Windows Explorer the application stop itself after launch. But if I open a new command line and make an:

```
adb install app-debug.apk
```

inside the **outputs/apk/** folder it works. I think that's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy file `outputs/apk/app-debug.apk` to run in Android device that not worked for me too. When I am trying to install `app-debug.apk` which crashed. I am trying to sign app first and choosing debug.

To do that:

1. Build -> Generate Signed APK
2. Filling the blank if you havent key store path, create new one. `https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html`
3. Choose build type is debug and choose both V1 and V2
4. Wait until finish.

Comment: It's gonna work if you make a Build -> Clean and Build -> Rebuild Project and then generate the apk. It should work, just enable Install app from other sources under security.